# Android AsyncTask take param from TextView

Tags: json, android-asynctask, parameters

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

I have a problem to add param in my url string, I need the url to be:

```
http://api.androidhive.info/contacts?email=params
```

and params is that the contents of a TextView, I'm trying to take params like that:

```
String email = emailget.getText().toString();
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("email", email);
```

but after how and where should I use this parameter to make sure that the URL is this:

```
http://api.androidhive.info/contacts?email=params
```

I need that because in my web service my sql query is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Contact 
WHERE email = ?
```

and I take the query param like that:

```
@QueryParam("email") String email)
```

Someone can help me to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use StringBuilder to appemd the params....

Could you please show more code?

Comment: Hi Raj Sharma, the code is the same of the tutorial, you can see it at this link:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/
Look ServiceHandler class...I don't understand how put params taking it from TextView....
I had just added only a code to take string by TextView
Can you explain how to use StringBuilder?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
        // If Your are using a Post Method than add a Params in List Name  value pair.

        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email",xyx@gmail.com));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",12345678));


       // Post a request from server

public static  String post(String url,List<NameValuePair> params)
{
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,"UTF-8"));   
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            respone=line.trim();
        }
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    return respone;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adam but I need to use Get Method only for send correct request to web server.
Client Android send Http request like this:
http://api.androidhive.info/contacts?email=params
web service execute the query like this:
"SELECT * FROM Contact where email = ?"
and return json

so I just need to send a correct request with param from my textview....

Comment: params.get(0).getValue(); to get a value of email

Comment: params.get(1).getValue(); get the value of password. I hope may be helpful

Comment: Thanks Adam for your help, I don't understand very well how to use your example but I fix anyhow using:
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get("http://api.androidhive.info/contacts",params ,new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()

Comment: @Niel can you help me with the same...i didnt understand